# I need advice for developing flutter based Android-app with using langchain

Tags: android, flutter, langchain, large-language-model, google-publisher-tag

i recently plan to make an android application which is written by Flutter.
In this app, i will add chatting function based on llm which will be connected with langchain.
In this case, how to insert this langchain function to flutter?

Acutally, i think this kind of chat function is usually developed by Python.
So, is there any way to insert this python code to my android app? Or just make that langchain in Dart language?
Since i'm a beginner, i do not know much well.

If you can help me, i will really appreciate it. Thank you!

maybe to convert chat function to API?
I'm not sure how to plan and direct my android application development.

Comment: You said, "insert this python code". Please share some code so we can figure out what is going on.